# How to communicate with jQuery in Django?

Tags: python, jquery, django

I got this script in 
 
**index.html**

```
    <script>
       $(window).on("scroll", function() {
           if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
             alert("Bottom of page!");
           }
       });
    <script>
```

and this in my

**views.py**

```
def entry(request,
    template='index.html',
    page_template='entry_list_page.html'):
    context = {
        'entry_list': Entry.objects.filter()[:4],
        'page_template': page_template,
    }
    if request.is_ajax():
        template = page_template
    return render(request, template, context)
```

How can I let Django know that jQuery has hit the bottom of the page so that I could display 4 more Entry objects?

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass information from client-side code (jQuery) to server-side (views.py) you'll need to use AJAX. [This](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/ajax.html) tutorial explains how to pass information about a press of a like button, the code should be fairly straight-forward to modify for integrating with your Python and jQuery code.